# Simple xml menu (action bar) runs fine on Nexus7 but crashes on phones with android 4.0

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/next_page"
        android:title="@string/next"
        android:onClick="next_page"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" 
        android:orderInCategory="2"  />
    <item android:id="@+id/begin_calc"
        android:title="@string/begin"
        android:onClick="initial_values"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:orderInCategory="1"  />
</menu>
```

Why would this run fine on the Nexus 7, but crash upon loading, on two other newer phones running android 4.0.4 and 4.0.3 ??

It also runs fine on the emulator: manifest includes:

```
<application
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

which works as it should, on the emulator

if I remove the onClick lines it will run on the phones, but obviously those lines are the whole point

Never mind :)

I found another way that works, forget using the onClick xml, use instead:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) { 
    case R.id.next_page_u_fool:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, A02_Second_page.class));
        break;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, A01_First_page.class)); 
        break;
    case R.id.begin_calc_or_puke:
        read_fields_first_page(); 
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Rvb_Initial_values_1.class));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

put that in my Activity after the  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

Eclipse spits out the following:

AndroidRuntime(25734): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
AndroidRuntime(25734): android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler next_page in class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.(MenuInflater.java:202)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:402)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:436)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:173)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:95)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at ( my package etc) .A01_First_page.onCreateOptionsMenu(A01_First_page.java:54)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2501)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:415)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:805)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2985)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime(25734): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: next_page [interface android.view.MenuItem]
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.(MenuInflater.java:200)
AndroidRuntime(25734):  ... 18 more

Comment: post the stacktrace of the crash

Comment: simply remove the 'onClick' references from the menu

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might come across this in future... The first bit - with the XML - I think you need to have next_page and initial_values as methods in your activity...

```
public void next_page(View v){
    ...
}

public void initial_values(View v){
    ...
}
```

As mentioned above, you can also use onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: How on earth do you think it ran on my nexus 7 WITHOUT those methods in my Activity?